# Processing 3.3.7 Carmichael function

Tags: processing, modulo

So I am trying to make a carmichael function in processing for some RSA encryption stuff I am playing with, but the modulo function seems to give many wrong answers.
here is my code:

```java
int carmichael(int n) {
  int checkIndex = 0;
  int m = 1;
  ArrayList<Integer> coprimes = findCoprimesLessThan(n);

  println(coprimes);

  for(m = 1; m < 50; m++){
    for(checkIndex = 0; checkIndex < coprimes.size(); checkIndex++){
      int a = coprimes.get(checkIndex);
      float mod = pow(a, m) % n;

      println(a, m, n, mod, pow(a, m), pow(a, m) % n);

      if (mod == 1) {
        continue;
      }
      if (mod != 1){
        break;
      }
      return m;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

And for an input of say, 31, it loops forever (I have it stop at 100 just for this reason so it just outputs 1 if it goes through all 100 and doesn't find anything) when it should give 30. I believe I have narrowed it down to the modulo operation not working on large numbers as that seems to be the problem, for example:
when a = 3, m = 30, and n = 31, my println statement gives this:

```java
3 30 31 18.0 2.05891136E14 18.0
```

and all of that is correct *except* the modulo, it gives 18.0 when it should be 1.0. I am unsure of anyway to get around this as even doing a "manual modulus" like this:

```java
while(mod >= n){
  mod-= n;
}
```

results in the exact same problem. All research I have done into the carmichael function has led me to either confusion or [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93739/compute-the-carmichael-function) which was no help.

Comment: Can you narrow your code down to a [mcve] that uses hard-coded values to demonstrates exactly what input and output you're confused about?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Didn't I?

Comment: If I were you, I'd [debug my code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) until I had it narrowed down to a single line. Then I'd ask a question like `why is X % Y equal to Z instead of A?` Right now it's hard to run your code because the line you're talking about is in the middle of a double-nested `for` loop inside a function, so it's a little hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're hitting a limit of float precision.

Float values can only track a certain amount of precision. Try running this example program:

```java
float one = 123456789;
float two = one + 1;
println(one == two);
```

You would expect this to print `false`, but if you run it, you'll see that it prints `true` instead. This is because we're outside the bounds of precision.

To get around this, you could upgrade to the `double` type. Double values have the same problem, but at a higher level of precision.

```java
double one = 123456789;
double two = one + 1;
println(one == two);
```

Getting back to your code, by default Processing treats everything as a `float` value. This is fine for most cases, but if you need lots of precision then you're better off switching to `double` value.

```java
int a = 3;
int m = 30;
int n = 31;

double p = Math.pow(a, m);
println(p);

double mod = p % n;

println(mod);
```

Note that I'm using `Math.pow()` instead of `pow()`. The `Math.pow()` function comes from Java and takes and returns `double` values instead of `float` values.

(By the way, this is the type of example program I was talking about in the comments.)

Comment: Is there anything above double? I am dealing with numbers like 30 ^ 30 here, and a single digit off will ruin the whole thing.

Comment: @yourdoom Sure, you could look into using the `BigDecimal` class.

Comment: That is what I found when I looked it up and they are very useful as an arbitrary precision number class, but they are kind of a pain to work with so I use them sparingly. But they worked nonetheless!